# Set a upper bandwidth limit for Infiniband HCAs

Tags: switch, bandwidth, pci-express, infiniband

I have to deal with *PCIe* congestion and I need to find a way to reduce *PCIe* traffic. I get several IB cards in one node (among other PCIe devices). HCAs are *FDR Infiniband*.

Putting those HCAs in *FDR-10* or *QDR* reduces too much the total bandwidth. Ideally I would like to limit each HCA to run between 5 and 5.5 GB/s. I'm not sure if a QoS managed by the IB switch could effectively set a upper limit per HCA (I think it rather uses weights for setting priorities).

Is there other ways to set a upper bandwidth limit for Infiniband HCAs?

Answer (score 0):

AFIK, there is no way to set a real limit to IB traffic other than changing link speed to a lower one.
IB QoS is about arbitration between different traffic streams, not about limiting a traffic BW.

You can, however, enable Congestion Control (if your SW/HW supports it).
It's not really what it is meant for - it's more for solving congestion on switches - but it might solve your issue as well.